# Xamarin Forms: Image Slider: CarouselPage - Out of Memory

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm using a CarouselPage to show a bunch of images and I want the user to be able to swipe through them. A CarouselPage would seem like the best option, but now that I'm using it I'm not so sure anymore.

My emulator keeps running out of memory, and when I test it on a real mobile device it crashes.
There are a total of 56 images that need to be shown, but the CarouselPage can't handle that. 
Is a CarouselPage suitable for such a task, if so: how can I make it faster.

This is the code I use for adding PhotoPages.

```
foreach (Photo p in Gallery.Photos) {
        // Get the photo path on device.
        string path = DataAccessor.GetPhotoPath (p);
        PhotoPage page= new PhotoPage (path);
        Children.Add (page);
}
```

*A PhotoPage is just an ImageView inside a ContentPage.*

So besides adding less children to the carouselpage, is there any way to use the Carouselpage as an Image Slider without out of memory exceptions or frozen screens? Or is there another solution to making an ImageSlider without using the CarouselPage.

Answer (score 3):

I have also faced similar issue.. What I have done so far is added let's say 5 pages, as I move on to next page remove the first child from the CarouselPage and add another child at the end of the CarouselPage. If you can manage of having limited amount of childs (eg: 5)  at a time you can avoid this exception.

In Android adding below line to manifest may help.

```
    <application android:largeHeap="true"></application>
```